# What would be the correct entity type for Password in Login (user_Login) intent?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

Hi my team is trying to create customized google actions using dialogflow. For that they have come up with some queries, please help -

In Login (user_Login) Intent, we are asking for Mobile number and password. What would be the correct entity type for password? Right now it is not able to detect the password.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Would it be possible to narrow down your question? At this moment it contains multiple questions and it is really hard to provide you with a proper answer. If you need some help with this, please look at the stackoverflow guidelines. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you so much for guiding me with this, i've updated the question now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be careful with handeling users passwords in a conversation. Because password are very random there isn't a standard entity that helps you with recognising it. The only way you could approach this is by using the @sys.any entity, which just takes in anything as input. This isn't a very secure approach because the user has to type or speak out their password.

The best approach would be to sign-in your users with one of the build in [accountlinking](https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity) features. These features can connect your action to your user database via OAuth and don't require you user to speak or type their password in the chat. This takes a lot of work out of your hands and makes your action more secure.

Comment: As suggested, I am trying to implementing Account Linking but facing issues. Please refer the URL

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62325054/getting-undefined-value-for-signin-status-during-account-linking

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62449329/getting-issue-during-re-calling-the-intent-after-rejecting-google-account-linkin
Hi Jordi, looking for you help