# How can we configure Context & Events in Inline Code editor

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

How can we configure Context & Events in Dialogflow Inline Code editor? 
I have tried the options below, but none of these is working.

```
app.intent('test1', (conv)=>{
 conv.Context.set({ name: 'weather', lifespan: 2, parameters: { city: 'Rome' }});   
  conv.followupEventInput.set({
     'name':'Event_Sample',
      "parameters": {
      "parameter-name-1": "parameter-value-1",
      "parameter-name-2": "parameter-value-2"
    },
    "languageCode": "en-US"
    });
});
//conv.setContext({ name: 'weather', lifespan: 2, parameters: { city: 'Rome' }});   
//conv.setfollowupEventInput({ name: 'event-name', languageCode: 'en-US', parameters: { parameter-name-1: 'parameter-name-1', parameter-name-2: 'parameter-name-2' }});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set a context you need to call `conv.contexts.set()` and provide a name and lifespan for the context. Optionally you can provide parameters that you can send to a next turn in the conversation. An example would be:

```
conv.contexts.set("Foo", 5, {foo: "bar"});
```

In your code example calling `Context.set()` instead of `contexts.set()` and you used `{ }` around the parameters, so you are providing one object instead of three seperate values. This is most likely why you context isn't working.

The same goes for your follow-up event. You are calling `FollowupEventInput()` instead of `followup()` and you have are setting the parameters with a single object due to the `{ }`, so remove those.

More info and examples on [context](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/interfaces/dialogflow.context.html) and [follow-up events](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/dialogflow.dialogflowconversation.html#followup) can be found in the docs.

Comment: Hi jordi, looking for your help on this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62449329/getting-issue-during-re-calling-the-intent-after-rejecting-google-account-linkin

Comment: I see you un-accepted this post, what about it didn't work for you?

Comment: conv.ask("Some content I need to show"); 
conv.followup( "EventCalling", { para1: "para1", para2: "para1" }); 

Here the response mentioned in Intent (calling via Event EventCalling ) is overwrite the topmost comment. How come we can merge both the content.

Comment: Please edit your question if you have any additional information, that makes it easier to understand.

Comment: The above solution regarding Context & events is working as expected.  
Here is my doubt. I am displaying some information using the command Conv.ask(), just after that I am calling an Intent via Event and showing more information. 
What exactly it is doing, it is ignoring the command mentioned in Conv.ask() and redirecting to the intent and showing that particular data only. How can I merge or show both pieces of information to the user?

Comment: Please make a new question for this and add all the details there, it makes it easier for me.

Comment: I have created one intent with the context name "Feedback-followup" and the passing parameter "QuestionNos". When trying to reading it via inline code editor, I am getting exception (TypeError: Cannot read property 'parameters' of undefined at app.intent)
Below is the code I am using----
const context1 = conv.contexts.get("Feedback-followup");
const { QuestionNos } = context1.parameters;