# Unlinking the Google account from DialogFlow conversation

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

How can we Unlink the google account from the particular intent in inline code?
There are no built-in actions to trigger sign out like there are for sign in (actions_intent_SIGN_IN).

Suppose user by mistaken logged in via some another account and now he wants to switch. How we can provide this facility?

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible to unlink the Account via Voice. But the user can reset the Account at the Action Directory on the bottom of the side.