# Getting Issue during re-calling the intent after rejecting Google Account linking

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, google-assist-api

Below is my chatbot structure
Intent 1 (result): Here User will ask for a result. It will do the account linking and check the email id registration on their server whether it is registered or not via API and showing the result.

```
app.intent('result', (conv,{date})=>{ 
var userDate =  date;     
var apiUserEmailID=  conv.data.apiUserEmailID;   
var apiUserKey= conv.data.apiUserKey;    
console.log("apiUserKey : "+apiUserKey); 
if (typeof (apiUserKey) == "undefined" || apiUserKey == "" || apiUserKey == null) 
{
 conv.ask(new SignIn('To get your account details'));// Intent that starts the account linking flow.  
}
else
{   
 conv.ask("Welcome to quote generator"+userDate+" Session : "+apiUserKey); 
**//Flow should come here when ask for the next time after Google account linking**
}  
}); 

app.intent('user_Login', (conv, params, signin) => {// Create a Dialogflow intent with the `actions_intent_SIGN_IN` event.  
if (signin.status === 'OK') 
{ 
const payload = conv.user.profile.payload;    
conv.data.apiUserEmailID=payload.email; //Session Creation    
var url = apiPathAJ+'/CheckAccess?uid=payload.email';  
var login_response="",login_Userkey="";    
return getaxiosURL(url).then(response => {  
response.data.map(loginObj=>{    
if(loginObj.Status=="TRUE")
{login_response = "1";
login_Userkey=loginObj.UserKey;}
else     
{login_response = "0";  
login_Userkey="0";}    
}); 
if(login_response=="1")
  {
   conv.data.apiUserKey=login_Userkey;   
   conv.ask("You are a registered User with Our Service. Here is your result *******");
  }
  else 
  { 
    conv.ask("You are not a registered User. Would you like to proceed with the Service registration.");
  }
}).catch (error => {
login_response="2";
console.log("Something is wrong in login_response("+login_response+") !! " + error);   
});
 
}
else 
  {
    conv.ask(`I won't be able to save your data, but what do you want to do next?`);
  }  
});
```

**Below is the conversation example.** 
*User: I want to see my result for 25th June 2019. 

ChatBot:.....(It will ask for the account linking) 

User: Yes 

ChatBot:You are a registered User with Our Service. 

User: I want to see my result for 25th June 2019.*

**Another conversation example.** 
*User: I want to see my result for 25th June 2019. 

ChatBot:.....(It will ask for the account linking) 

User: No

ChatBot:I won't be able to save your data, but what do you want to do next? 

User: I want to see my result for 25th June 2019.*

**In both the conversation, If user will ask the same question(user's last comment) or we can say it hits the intent (result), i am getting this exception and the conversation is existing.**

> Error: Dialogflow IntentHandler not found for intent:
> user_Login-result at Function.
> (/srv/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:141:31)
> at Generator.next () at fulfilled
> (/srv/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:19:58)
> at  at process._tickDomainCallback
> (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests that the "result-dailyPrediction" Intent is the one that has matched in Dialogflow, but there is no handler registered with `app.intent('result-dailyPrediction')`.

You should either register such an intent handler, or figure out why you're getting to that Intent and correct it (if it shouldn't be there).

Comment: I have updated the question with more clarity. Please check that and reply.